# Force style usage in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, templates, styles

### Background

Develop a consistent, professional-quality corporate template using Microsoft Word.

### Problem

People use their own fonts, change styles, and generally make a mess of standardization. This makes it time consuming to change the appearance of all documents to a specific standard.

### Question

In Microsoft Word 2010, how would you create a template that:

- Eliminates the ability to change the fonts in a document.
- Prevents adding new styles.
- Forces users to use styles.
- Provides very few styles (e.g., body, three headings, header, footer).

Basically, I want to restrict the documents so that people can only picks styles when editing. They should not be able to modify styles, either.

### Related Links

- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/style-basics-in-word-HA010230882.aspx#BM4
- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/is-there-a-way-to-lock-the-styles-in-the-top/904bc40d-075f-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5
- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/restrict-or-permit-formatting-changes-HA010372712.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe [this illustrated guide](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/restrict-editing-to-secure-word-2010-document/) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513000627/https://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/restrict-editing-to-secure-word-2010-document/)) can help you.

In a few lines, Word 2010 has the "Restrict Editing" function (menu Review) that gives you a large choice of restrictions. Even suggested restriction can be applied.

If I correctly understood your question, I think you will achieve your objective.

Comment: The instructions should be summarized in case the link ever becomes unavailable.