# Is it possible to restrict formatting to Template Styles in Word 2016

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-office-2016

My goal is to create templates in Word 2016 that enforce following a set of fonts and sizes, but I can't figure out how to delete the styles I don't need, or how to restrict the user to use only those styles.

Similar questions to this have been asked before, such as:

[Force style usage in Microsoft Word](https://superuser.com/questions/353034/force-style-usage-in-microsoft-word)

but these pertain to older versions of Word and I can't find any similar settings in office 365. I'm using word for Mac, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't author the restrictions in Word for Mac - it currently doesn't have this functionality.  It will, however, honor any restrictions that are defined in a word file.  So if you create the documents and enforce the style rules from a Windows copy - you can use that file on Mac and get the result.

Microsoft uses a site called UserVoice to track requests for certain features.  If there is enough push for it, they will get it on the roadmap to implement.  Right now, this particular item I found was requested - but it has not received much attention.  You can add your vote to it here though:  https://word.uservoice.com/forums/304942-word-for-mac/suggestions/13414068-https-support-office-com-en-us-article-restrict

Comment: Thanks, this is the workaround I eventually found. Word on Windows is really bad at fonts though, so I have to bounce back and forth and back and forth.